# How Do I Change The Startup command In An Azure Web App Without The Portal?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-webapps

I am [using this guide](http://ttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/deploy-nodejs-azure-app-service-with-visual-studio-code) to deploy my ReactJS web app to Azure.

After following the steps I need to go into the portal and set the Startup command to `npx serve -l 8080 build`.

Is it possible to make this change from within Visual Studio Code?

Eventually, I am going to change from VSCode to `az cli` to make it more automated.

Is it possible to set this value using the command line?

Answer (score 0):

```
az webapp config set --startup-file="some_cmd"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_set-optional-parameters