# Azure Windows Web App Node customize strart up script

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

Using DevOps Pipelines and Artifacts + Azure Web App (Windows) -> I'm trying to deploy server + website on the same machine.

It currently looks like a default node server is running and just waiting for static site on `wwwroot` folder.

But is there a way to specify and tell azure with which **node.js script** it should start the server?

In this example : [Node quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-azure-portal) they just push an "app.js" to `wwwroot` folder and it works.... they give info about how to change port but in my case I want to stop that default process and start mine !

I want to run my own server.

Comment: there's an option to run startup-command refer here- https://i.imgur.com/bzrhFTm.png in the yaml AzurermWebappDeployment04 task same option is available in Release pipeline task too

Comment: @SiddheshDesai that is only for Linux server , thank you

Comment: In Azure App Service Deploy task select Windows > https://i.imgur.com/8Xx4oh9.png and then add the startup command in configuration section like here- https://i.imgur.com/uib394D.png For release pipeline refer here- https://i.imgur.com/douP0Aw.png

Comment: Thank you @SiddheshDesai looks like it work with no error but . On kudu when i run the same command (in same port) i dont have any error saying "port already taken"

Comment: In kudu when I manually start my server on port 8080 my site donsent work , webpage says "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Comment: Check your path mapping in your azure web app is set to site/wwwroot/myapp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254934/discussion-between-siddheshdesai-and-borisd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried deploying ***node.js application in Azure Web app (Windows) > While using Azure app service deploy task I added the start up command to run `nodejs App.js` like below in my YAML pipeline and the deployment was successful***, Refer below:-

**My YAML pipeline:-**

**App Type selected as Windows:-**

[image]

**Add Start up command in the same task:-**

[image]

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:

  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxx-xxxx0-xxx25653'

  
  webAppName: 'valleywebapp628'

  
  environmentName: 'valleywebapp628'

 
  vmImageName: 'windows-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
         targetType: 'inline'
         script: '$env:servicePrincipalId '
   

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: siliconwebapp655'
            inputs:
              ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: 'webApp'
              WebAppName: '$(webAppName)'
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              ScriptType: 'Inline Script'
              InlineScript: |
                npm install
                npm run build --if-present
              ConfigurationSettings: '-startup-file node App.js'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

***For Release pipeline you can add the startup command for Windows Web app like below:-***

[image]

**Configuration settings:-**

```
-startup-file node App.js
```

[image]

**Reference:-**

[javascript - How Do I Change The Startup command In An Azure Web App Without The Portal? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65310252/how-do-i-change-the-startup-command-in-an-azure-web-app-without-the-portal) By silent